# Trying to run Django app on Gunicorn locally using Foreman

Tags: django, heroku, virtualenv, gunicorn, foreman

I'm following [Getting Started with Django on Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django)
When I'm trying to run Django app on the Gunicorn using Foreman, i get next error traceback:

```
09:23:33 web.1  | started with pid 7012  
09:23:34 web.1  | 2013-05-06 09:23:34 [7012] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.2  
09:23:34 web.1  | 2013-05-06 09:23:34 [7012] [INFO] Listening at: `http://0.0.0.0:5000` (7012)  
09:23:34 web.1  | 2013-05-06 09:23:34 [7012] [INFO] Using worker: sync  
09:23:34 web.1  | 2013-05-06 09:23:34 [7015] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7015  
09:23:34 web.1  | 2013-05-06 09:23:34 [7015] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:  
09:23:34 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 485, in spawn_worker  
09:23:34 web.1  |     worker.init_process()  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process  
09:23:34 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 103, in wsgi  
09:23:34 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 25, in load  
09:23:34 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 372, in import_app  
09:23:34 web.1  |     __import__(module)  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/Users/cosmicMan66/DjangoDev/hepcat_server/hepcat_server/wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>  
09:23:34 web.1  |     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  
09:23:34 web.1  | ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi  
09:23:34 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 485, in spawn_worker  
09:23:34 web.1  |     worker.init_process()  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process  
09:23:34 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 103, in wsgi  
09:23:34 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 25, in load  
09:23:34 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 372, in import_app  
09:23:34 web.1  |     __import__(module)  
09:23:34 web.1  |   File "/Users/cosmicMan66/DjangoDev/hepcat_server/hepcat_server/wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>  
09:23:34 web.1  |     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  
09:23:34 web.1  | ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi  
09:23:34 web.1  | 2013-05-06 09:23:34 [7015] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7015)  
09:23:35 web.1  | 2013-05-06 09:23:35 [7012] [INFO] Shutting down: Master  
09:23:35 web.1  | 2013-05-06 09:23:35 [7012] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.  
09:23:35 web.1  | exited with code 3  
09:23:35 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes  
SIGTERM received
```

Procfile is located in the root directory of a project and contains:

> web: gunicorn hepcat_server.wsgi

settings.py is located in hepcat_server directory

when I use `$ python manage.py run_gunicorn`
gunicorn starts successfully and I see default Django page

Comment: Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/johnnylambada/5505071) -- it's my complete log of how I got DJANGO tutorials 1 & 2 to work with Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue while following the Heroku setup page you were using. I found a solution on [this page](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/solved-foreman-start-importerror-no-module-named-wsgi/607/2). I've copied it here for posterity:

> In the root directory of your django project, create the Procfile file.
>   then write this on it web: sh -c "cd djangoproject && gunicorn
>   djangoproject.wsgi". then create another file called .env in the same
>   location, write DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djangoproject.settings into it,
>   this will help you setting the required env variable that cannot be
>   set in djangoproject.wsgi module. run foreman start in order to test.
>   What this does should be self explanatory giving the issue below.
>
> When you deploy, after creating your application in heroku, set the
>   env variable with this command heroku config:set
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djangoproject.settings, this is because the
>   deployment fails before the file djangoproject/djangoproject/wsgi.py
>   is run.

remember to replace "djangoproject" with the name of your django project.